# Выделить определенный текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте,у меня в textarea находится текст такого вида

```
<strong>Hello</strong> <p class="r">world</p>
```

Как мне теги выделить?Например поменять им цвет или шрифт,а то,что не в тегах, оставить не изменяя?

Answer (score 3):

Ну насколько я знаю - то никак. Внутри textarea весь код/текст есть простым набором символов, а не HTML.

Для чего используется textarea ? Может заменить textarea на простой div ?

Comment: ,не заменить не вариант,я думал мало ли через регулярное,как нибудь.

Comment: Выделить то можна, но стилизировать никак. Почему нельзя заменить ?

Comment: заменить на div?

Comment: да, какая у Вас задача стоит? Для чего используется textarea ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать элемент `div` с атрибутом `contenteditable="true"`, если требуется сохранить возможность редактирования текста внутри элемента.